# Updating on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onload

At the moment, the following JavaScript updates the cart's values on `click` when the "add to cart" button is clicked.

I am trying to make the values update on `pageload`, when page is loaded or refreshed.

At the moment the values only update on `click`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-cart').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-cart').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

            if (json['success']) {
                $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        },
    });
});
//--></script>
```

I have tried many things and have had no luck I have tried to load the values in using this (which doesn't do anything):

```
function readyFn( jQuery ) {
    $('#cart > button').load(function() {

                $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');


}); 

$( document ).ready( readyFn );
// or:
$( window ).on( "load", readyFn );
}
```

Just wondering if anyone can help me with how to load on refresh / page `load` in the same manner it updates on `click`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misplaced your closing brace on `readyFn`, so the document ready handler was inside the function. Also, you don't need to do anything when the button loads ( `$('#cart > button').load` ) because you're already waiting for the document to be ready before calling the function. Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
    $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
});
```

Note that `$(function(){})` is just a [shorthand](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will note that for future. Didn't fix my problem but useful information thanks!